# Spinners not working as they should, How to resolve?

Tags: android

Hey guys I have code shown bellow, which is supposed to get the item selected from the first spinner - Poets and then show another spinner depending on input poem 1,2 or 3.  Once An item is selected from the second spinner it should then show a text view.

My problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it chooses randomly which spinner to show it would seem and almost every single time when I select an item from spinner 2, the text view is almost never shown and when it is it's normally text view entitled tree.

can anyone help? I do not see any errors so I am confused

code:

```
public class Poets extends Activity implements  OnItemSelectedListener{

//defining variables
Spinner PoetSpinner, PoemSpinner1, PoemSpinner2, PoemSpinner3;
String Poets[] = {"","Robert Burns", "James Beattie", "Duncan MacGregor Crerar"};
String Poems1[] ={"", "Tam O Shanter", "Auld Lang Syne"};
String Poems2[] ={"", "Judgement Of Paris", "The Minstrel"};
String Poems3[] ={"", "A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns", "My Bonnie Rowan Tree"};

TextView Tam, Auld, Judge, TheMin, rob, tree ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set to fullscreen mode
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    //set content view 
    setContentView(R.layout.poet);

    initialize(); //call this method
}

public void initialize(){

    //initializing items that are in the class
    PoetSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoet);
    PoemSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem1);
    PoemSpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem2);
    PoemSpinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem3);
    Tam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem1);
    Auld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem2);
    Judge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem3);
    TheMin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem4);
    rob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem5);
    tree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem6);
    //setting up array adapters
    //
    //for each spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.poet_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.poem_arrays1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.poem_arrays2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.poem_arrays3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    PoetSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    PoetSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    PoemSpinner1.setAdapter(adapter2);
    PoemSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    PoemSpinner2.setAdapter(adapter3);
    PoemSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    PoemSpinner3.setAdapter(adapter4);
    PoemSpinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

      String val = Poets[pos];
      String val2 = Poems1[pos];
      String val3 = Poems2[pos];
      String val4 = Poems3[pos];
       if (val.equals("Robert Burns")) {
          PoemSpinner2.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
          PoemSpinner1.setVisibility(Spinner.VISIBLE);
          PoemSpinner3.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
       }
       if (val.equals("James Beattie")) {
              PoemSpinner2.setVisibility(Spinner.VISIBLE);
              PoemSpinner1.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
              PoemSpinner3.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
           }
       if (val.equals("Duncan MacGregor Crerar")) {
            PoemSpinner2.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
            PoemSpinner1.setVisibility(Spinner.GONE);
            PoemSpinner3.setVisibility(Spinner.VISIBLE);
           }
       if (val2.equals("Tam O Shanter")) {
            Tam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Auld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Judge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TheMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       if (val2.equals("Auld Lang Syne")) {
            Auld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Judge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TheMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Tam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       if (val3.equals("Judgment Of Paris")) {
            Judge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TheMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Tam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Auld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       if (val3.equals("The Minstrel")) {
            TheMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Tam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Auld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Judge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       if (val4.equals("A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns")) {
            rob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Tam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Auld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Judge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TheMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       if (val4.equals("My Bonnie Rowan Tree")) 
            tree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Tam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Auld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Judge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TheMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you have overcomplicated things a little. You can make what you want with 2 spinners and only one textview. 
The first spinner will contain the poets, and based on the poet selected in this spinner you can modify the content of the second spinner in which you can have the poems of the selected poet. You can then show the selected poems name in the textview when the poem is selected in the second spinner. I would try with something like this:

```
    public class Poets extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener {

  // defining variables
  Spinner PoetSpinner, PoemSpinner;
  String Poets[] = { "", "Robert Burns", "James Beattie",
  "Duncan MacGregor Crerar" };
  String Poems1[] = { "", "Tam O Shanter", "Auld Lang Syne" };
  String Poems2[] = { "", "Judgement Of Paris", "The Minstrel" };
  String Poems3[] = { "", "A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns",
  "My Bonnie Rowan Tree" };

  TextView selectedPoem;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set to fullscreen mode
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // set content view
    setContentView(R.layout.poet);

    initialize(); // call this method
  }

  public void initialize() {

    // initializing items that are in the class
    PoetSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoet);
    PoemSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem);
    // Hide the second spinner
    PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    selectedPoem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectPoem1);
    // setting up array adapters
    //
    // for each spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
    .createFromResource(this, R.array.poet_arrays,
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    PoetSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    PoetSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    PoemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Object poem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        selectedPoem.setText(poem.toString());
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
  }

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
    long id) {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
    switch (pos) {
      case 1:
      adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.poem_arrays1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      break;
      case 2:
      adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.poem_arrays2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      break;
      case 3:
      adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.poem_arrays3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      break;
      default:
      // Hide the poem spinner
      PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      break;
    }

    if (adapter != null) {
      // Set the poem spinners content and show the spinner
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      PoemSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

  }

}
```

Of course you will have to delete the unused views from your xml. 
I hope i was clear enough, and the code works as you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if there is any problem with the code i wrote, i did not try it in action.

Comment: Yes I am getting a red underline error on "adapter in the very bottom part for all three in nthe if(adapter != null) part. the hints say initialize adapter but I don't know what to initialize it.

Comment: This should do the trick: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yea thanks, figured that out just after asking.  One more problem everything works but I do not get how to set the text View as I do not get any poem showing at this time.  For reference each poem exert is stored in values for strings

Comment: So when you select a poet, the poem spinner appears but there are no poems in it when you click on it, so you cannot select any poem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26200/discussion-between-csaba-szugyiczki-and-thomas)